Fantasy novel with a girl, a satyr, and a gorgon escaping a circus
I'm trying to recall the name of a book I read when I was younger, it was fairly large, presumably 800-1000 pages, the protagonist was a demi-human, young and male, I can't recall exactly what he was but I believe he was a Satyr. One of the characters was an Asian female with foot bindings that made her feet look small, another character was a pregnant gorgon, these three and other characters were in cages for some sort of circus for which they escape close to the middle of the novel.
A scene I remember includes the protagonist treating the girl's feet so as to unbind them to allow her to walk better.
A scene close to the end includes a hero (I believe Perseus) fighting and killing the gorgon who in her dying breath gives birth to her baby, the protagonist and his group collect the child and leave.
I read this novel nearly 10 years ago and just recently started looking for it again. I will try and add more details to the description if I can recall any.

Perhaps the Corydon Trilogy, starting with Corydon and the Island of Monsters, by Tobias Druitt.
Corydon and the Island of Monsters was published in 2005, so it fits within your time frame. Corydon, the main character, (while not explicitly labelled a Satyr) is described as having one human foot, one goat's foot. Corydon befriends a couple of Gorgons; Stheno, Euryale and a pregnant Medusa.
Quite early into the novel Corydon is captured by pirates and kept in a cage (the metal house):

“Look what I've found here, Captain!” he called eagerly. “A new attraction! Just look at his leg! He's a right funny one and no mistake.”
The captain clambered up the slope. “I've never seen this before,” he said.
“One of his legs is shaped like a goat's leg. Great gods! Add him to the other freaks.”
[...]
“After all the men had looked at him, a kind of metal house was brought out. He was shoved into it, and the metal house was loaded onto a cart, like the others.”

Corydon then meets Medusa, who explains they have been captured to perform in the show:

“They don't have a name yet for what I am,” said the voice, “but my own name used to be Medusa. You can call me that, if you like. That's what they call me in the show.”
“What show?”
“That's what we're all here for, you know. The Show. The big striptease. Where the pirates put us on display and charge people money to see it.”

Medusa gives birth very early on, so while there is a scene near the end of the book where a hero (who is indeed Perseus) fights and kills her, it doesn't play out exactly as you recall but still closely enough:

Purple blood flowed in a river across the floor as Medusa tilted slowly forward. Perseus freed his sword with a jerk, and she toppled facedown.
Corydon ran forward, uncaring. He reached her side just as Perseus, triumphant, roaring, brought his sword down on Medusa's neck and severed her head from her body.


I do believe this is the book, the name Corydon very much feels familiar. Thanks for that.
